# Проверка текста на соответствие JS (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как проверить текст на наличие в нем заранее заданных ключевых слов или выражений?

Есть некая `<textarea>` в ней должен быть изначально некий текст, потом пользователь вводит свой и если, то что он ввел совпадает с теми ключами которые заранее заданны показываем ему кнопку далее.

В общем набросал два небольших скрипта, но первый работает только если присутствует одно ключевое слово, а второй работает так как надо, но только если текст был введен заранее, а на новый текст он не реагирует.

**Первый скрипт**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check (id, sbm) { 
if (document.getElementById(id).value == 'привет') document.getElementById(sbm).style.display = ''; 
};
</script> 
<form> 
<textarea type="text" id="pole"></textarea> 
<input type="button" value="Проверить" onclick="check('pole','sbm');"> 
<input type="submit" id="sbm" value="Далее" style="display:none"> 
</form>
```

**Второй скрипт**

```
 <script> 
    $(document).ready(function (){ 
    $(".check").click(function check(){ 
    $("textarea:contains(привет)").html(function(){$("#next").css("display", "block");}) 
      }); 
    }); 
   </script>
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь, ибо в JS не силен два дня уже вожусь с этим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    var chk = $('.check');

    var check = function(){
        var text = 'привет',
            el = $('.code'),
            btn = $('#next'),
            re = new RegExp(text, "gi");

        if (re.test(el.val())) {
            btn.show();
            $('.err').hide();
        } else {
            $('.err').show();
            btn.hide();
        }
    }


    chk.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        check();
    });

    check();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле всё очень просто. Обращаясь к документации *jquery* делаем следующий вывод или легкое изменение:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var check = $( "input:first" ).val()
  if ( check == "correct" || check == "ok" || check == "good") {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }

  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

или более закрученный вариант:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var check = $( "input:first" ).val()
  if ( ["correct", "ok", "good"].indexOf($( "input:first" ).val().toLowerCase())!= -1) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }
  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

В данном случае задаем массив возможных значений, плюс экстра бонус: `.toLowerCase` убедиться, что `OK == ok`.

Ну и сам пример [здесь](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/Ywzaav).

Comment: Да, это практически то что нужно, Спасибо большое)
Но необходимо сделать что бы оно среди прочего текста находило correct, ok, или good.
То есть допустим если заранее есть <textarea>У тебя все ок?</textarea>, и если человек дополнительно к этому тексту вводит допустим "good или другой ключ"   что бы валидация проходила успешно.

В целом что бы среди прочего текста если найдено ключевое слово, то валидация должна быть успешна.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать placeholder? Пусть там будет этот текст:
'<input placeholde="У тебя всё ок?">' Кликает на эту строчку, плэйсхолдер пропадает (ну или какая там нужна анимация), а потом вводит да/нет/ок. Я так понимаю это готовится опросник? я бы реализовал это через placeholder.
Обновил код в примере.

Comment: нет, placeholder не подходит, потому что это будут уроки по английскому языку и там заранее будет текст который надо будет дополнить или изменить.

Comment: Обновил код. Можно так попробовать реализовать.

Comment: Спасибо, но надо что бы весь текст был именно в textarea.
Кстати вот очень похожий пример, только тут с кодом https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/4/run/1